# JS find matching object from array in object

Tags: javascript

I have an array:

```js
let gid = ['554', '555', '564', '575', '618']
```

Then I have an object:

```js
let obj = {
  attr1: 'att',
  attr2: 'att2',
  attr3: [
    {
      attr: 'att',
      id: 554,
    },
    {
      attr: 'att',
      id: 555,
    },
    {
      attr: 'att',
      id: 1,
    },
  ],
};
```

How to I return the values of `obj.attr3.id` that match the values in `gid`?

Comment: what do you mean by match the values? and notice that obj.attr3.id is undefined

Comment: `obj.attr3.filter((item) => gid.includes(item.id)).map((item) => item.id)`

Comment: Remember that `obj.attr3` is an array, so you need to use `obj.attr3[0].id` etc.

Answer (score 0):

you should map the attr3 array.

```js
let matches = obj.attr3.map( (item, index) => item.id == gid[index])
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you might be asking for ?

```
obj.attr3.filter((item, index) => item.id == gid[index])
```